# JavaScript constructors

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

I'm trying to get a grip of javascript constructors and if they are really read-only. Here is a simple test scenario:

```
var A = function(){}

console.log( A.prototype.constructor == A ); //true
```

So at this point, every new function receives a prototype object that contains the constructor as a reference. That's all good. Now consider this:

```
var B = function() {
    this.id = 0;
}

A.prototype.constructor = B; // what does this do with A?
```

So now, every instance of A should get B as constructor:

```
var C = new A();

console.log(C.constructor == B) // true
```

So finally, does this have any real effect on each instance? It doesn't seem so:

```
console.log(C.id); // what will this yield?
```

My question is: what is the purpose of exposing a constructor reference? Apparently you can set/override it, but it doesn't do anything except changing the reference. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `constructor` property is just for convenience, it has absolutely no effect on how your program behaves. By default, when you define a function, `func.prototype.constructor` is set to `func` itself -- you can set it to whatever you want later and it makes no difference. The object that is constructed depends solely on the function that *you* pass to `new`: if you do `new A()`, it will always call function `A`.

Comment: Hi, every post, book, about javascript inheritance, tells us to fix the prototype constructor, after that situtation:
`A.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);`
`A.prototype.constructor = B //fixing here` 

I undestand what `Object.create` does, however the next line seems to be useless. I wrote some code removing it and that has no effect. So my question is, why everybody says to *fix* the constructor ?